# Regular expression for passwords with special characters

Tags: regex

Here is the regular expression i fount from microsoft's website

```
(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,10})$
```

and it `Validates a strong password. It must be between 8 and 10 characters, contain at least one digit and one alphabetic character, and must not contain special characters.`

But now we decide to allow user using special characters in their passwords, so how do I modify this regular expression? I don't quite understand why put `?!` in front.

Comment: Which special characters do you want to allow?

Comment: @robert now we only need the password contain at least one digit and one letter, so i think all the special characters.

Comment: Any time I see someone who puts an upper limit on acceptable password length, my first assumption is this means they are not hashing passwords correctly, because hashed passwords are a fixed length no matter how long the password is. Are you storing passwords in plain text? If so, that's the first problem that needs fixing, but if not, then why are you disallowing people from using a [correct horse battery staple](http://xkcd.com/936/)?

Comment: @GarrettAlbright this is from the microsoft site, in my situation, i don't have the maximum limit, user can any length they want, so I will remove "10" later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?!^[0-9]*$)` is a negative lookahead. This assertion fails if there are only digits from the start to the end. So, you have different possibilities:

I would rewrite those conditions to require at least one and not to forbid only that characters.

`(?=.*\d)` would require at least one digit

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` would require at least one letter

Your regex would then look something like this:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,10}$
```

means require at least one digit, one letter and consist of 8 to 10 characters. The `.` can be any character, but no newlines.

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?31bmr)

Comment: it works!! I do tried this pattern before, and somehow it didn't work. But I still don't understand why there is a "=", and can you explain "!" as well, i do want to be able to write it by myself instead of copying it. thanks

Comment: A group starting with `?=` is a positive lookahead and a group starting with `?!` is a negative lookahead, they are explained in detail on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).